# Can't install wkhtmltopdf locally for use with python - Windows 10 (pdfkit)

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, failed-installation, pdfkit

I am trying to convert a large list of URLs into .pdf files in python. I came accross pdfkit and it seems like it is a great solution to my problem. I did pip install pdfkit using anaconda prompt with no problem.

I am now trying to install the wkhtmltopdf.exe file and when i download the file from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html it starts the download.

When I click to actually install the download, it begins to run and installing to path C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf

After a few seconds I get an error that states:

```
Error opening file for writing 
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
Click Abort to stop the installation,
Retry to try again, or
Ignore to skip this file
```

I am on a Windows 10 machine. I have tried looking online and have no clue what could be wrong with trying to download this file

**EDIT:** McAfee was blocking the download because of updates that were being installed

Comment: These days I would consider Chrome Headless. Likely a much bigger download, but you can keep it up to date the same way you would Chrome, etc.: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Choose the right Windows version (32 bit/64 bit) when download from the official site, https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.

Maybe you want to consider:

1. Clear the registry if tried to install wkhtmltopdf before
2. Choose another path/folder to install
3. turn off anti-virus for the installation